# Does dask dataframe.persist() keep results for the next query?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, dask

I'm trying to understand how `df.persist()` works in `dask`. Would I build the same expression again, would it recalculate it or load it from cache?

E.g. what happens when I do:

```
ddf = dask.dataframe.read_csv('my.csv').shift(1).persist()
print(ddf.sum().compute())
del ddf
ddf = dask.dataframe.read_csv('my.csv').shift(1).persist()
print(ddf.mean().compute())
```

Does `dask` read the `.csv` and shift by one twice, or the second time it comes from cache? Do I need the second `.persist()`? If it keeps it in cache, how do I force cleaning the cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call persist it keeps the data in distributed memory so that you don't need to recompute that part of the computation a second time.

You can release the memory by deleting the collection, as you do in line 3.

If you delete the collection, then yes, you will need to re-persist the intermediate results.

https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/memory.html

Comment: Thanks! It became clear to me too, that persist is only persisting in RAM and holds it until the future returned by persist() is freed up.